# C# opening a new form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have looked through many topics with the same question but those answers don't work in my case.

I have 2 forms: Form2.cs and frmMain.cs. I want to open the Form2 on button click, so I have added the lines for a button in frmMain:

```
 private void PLCTagsMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Form2 form = new Form2();
       form.ShowDialog();

    }
```

but this errors for the "Form2"s:

```
CS0246 
The type or namespace name 'Form2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So what am I doing wrong? I am using VS 2015 RC

Comment: does the application compile? are you getting this exception while debugging or is it during compiling?

Comment: Have you changed the namespace that form2 is in?

Comment: Can you post Form2.cs content?

Comment: I'm certain this has been answered before. Please show what specific Stack Overflow questions you tried and why they didn't help. Did you go straight to the answers and copy the code, or did you try to understand what was being explained there? You need a `using Form2Namespace;` or you need to use the full namespace `Form2Namespace.Form2 form = new Form2Namespace.Form2();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If form2 is in another namespace, then you need to either use the full namespace or add a [`using` directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx):

```
Form2Namespace.Form2 = new Form2Namespace.Form2();
```

Or:

```
using Form2Namespace;
```

Comment: What is "include full path"?

Comment: Thank you. This was the case as the frmMain namespace was "S71200Driver" but the Form2 namespace was "S71200.Driver".
Changed the default namespace and Form2 namespace and now it's working!

Comment: @CodeCaster in this case full path would be "S71200.Driver.Form2"

Comment: I understand what you mean, but that is not called a "full path" nor an "include". Stack Overflow is a knowledge base, not a forum. We're not here to just help OP, but to create a collection of Q&As for future searchers. The term "include full path" doesn't mean anything in the .NET/C# world. Using proper nomenclature is important.

Comment: @Shaharyar i wonder why the need to edit my answer, as its obvious that my answer was enough understandable and helped already before your edit.

Comment: @MladenOršolić That was not clear enough, I edited for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Error was thrown in your code because compiler could not find the class `Form2`. I guess you are using **Form2** instead of **Form**

If so, change your code as follows

```
 private void PLCTagsMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Form form = new Form();
       form.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Note: `form.ShowDialog()` method will not dispose or the form. You need to manually dispose the form before closing it. Also, first form will not be accessible until you close the second form. If you want to access both the forms use `form.Show()` method.

If my guess is wrong, right click on the word **Form2** in visual studio, there will be an option **Resolve** in the context menu. It will show the namespaces that contains the class **Form2**. Choose the correct namespace and the error will be gone.

If you know the name space that contains the class **Form2**, you can also manually type it in the namespace section to avoid the error.